# What happens to Staff when a Congressman Resigns?

Tags: united-states, congress

Recently a number of high profile Senators and Congressmen have resigned.

I believe each of them has numerous staff, both in Washington DC and in their home state / district.

What happens to these staffers when their boss abruptly leaves?

Are they terminated immediately?

Are the DC Staff eligible for Unemployment Insurance?
*(from DC? from their home state? From the Federal Government)*

Do they get any benefits / severance?

I can imagine many of them have apartment leases and other commitments that may be incredibly stressful to maintain after suddenly losing their jobs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Washington Post ran an article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/reliable-source/post/what-happens-to-anthony-weiners-staff-when-the-boss-leaves-its-political-limbo-for-hill-aides/2011/06/17/AGDUw4bH_blog.html?utm_term=.74534fb4ff51) after Democratic Representative Anthony "don't let US government use the internet please!" Wiener resigned in 2011 following a sexting scandal. The article covered *some* details of this but not fully:

**Senate**

> In the Senate, staffers who lose their boss keep their jobs for only up to 60 days as employees of the Secretary of the Senate — no matter whom they worked for or how long. “I was out of a job,” a staffer for the late Sen. Edward M. Kennedy told us. “The job that you had ends with the member.”

**House**:

> The minute a representative leaves office, the staff begins working for the district and answers to the Clerk of the House, Karen Haas. The nameplate comes off the door; the office phone is answered generically. (“Twenty-sixth District of New York,” in Lee’s case.) Staffers provide constituent services in the D.C. and district offices, but there’s no voting power. The arrangement lasts until the swearing-in of a new member — who then has power to retain or fire any of the old staffers. From an employee standpoint, the House is like 435 small businesses constantly facing takeovers, hostile or benign.

---

[Texas Tribune covered a similar 2012 situation](https://www.texastribune.org/2012/06/20/when-legislators-die-or-resign-what-happens-to-the/), though in this case the congressperson resigned to take another job. The article details offer some promising leads on who can be asked for more details (*House Administration Committee*):

> State Rep. Veronica Gonzales, D-McAllen, will leave her seat June 30 when she officially resigns to take a position as the University of Texas-Pan American's vice president for university advancement. All of her staff members except one at the Capitol and one in her district office will be let go.
>
> "Her last day is all the staff's last day as well," said Jennifer Saenz, who provides general counsel for Gonzales' office. "Then we're all unemployed."
>
> The two remaining staff members will report to the House Administration Committee. Their duties will mostly consist of taking calls from constituents.
>
> There are no official rules that outline how the office should be run between when the vacancy occurs and when the new representative is elected — that is at the discretion of the House Administration Committee — but Gonzales' situation is typical of how vacant offices are run, said Steven Adrian, executive director of House business operations.

---

As far as unemployment etc..., since the staffers are ultimately employed by the House of Representatives, the [House employment policies kick in](https://www.house.gov/employment/information-for-former-employees).

## That page mentions both [continuation of health insurance](https://www.house.gov/sites/default/files/uploads/documents/FEHB-TCC.pdf) and [applying for unemployment](https://www.house.gov/sites/default/files/uploads/documents/SF8.pdf).

Also [this NYT arricle](http://www.nytimes.com/1994/12/13/us/congress-s-out-of-work-try-to-keep-smiling.html) gives a fluffy human interest story about poor staffers applying for unemployment in 1994. So presumably they can.

Also, Congressional Management Foundation has a handy publication called "[**Closing a Congressional Office**](http://www.congressfoundation.org/storage/documents/CMF_Pubs/cmf_closing_a_congressional_office_2014.pdf)".

It mentions unemployment explicitly, as well as offers further contact:

> Advise employees to obtain current information on issues of unemployment insurance and retirement programs by contacting the **House Finance Office and the Senate Disbursing Office**